# Golden Gate и восстановление данных

Tags: база-данных, oracle, goldengate

Есть 4 тестовых базы данных

[image: схема работы]

Данные по ГГ реплицируются с DB1 на DB2 -  затем передаются на DB3 и DB4 с помощью DATA GUARD'a, но в момент switchover'a, например с DB2 на DB3, дата памп останавливается, на DB3 создается репликат (в репликате добавляется поле HANDLECOLLISIONS), после переключение поднимается памп на DB1 и репликат на BD3, данные передаются нормально, но возникает проблема с отсутсвием данных на BD3 которые были записаны в DB1. К примеру в момент switchover'a в BD1, было  записано 3 поля ($1), после того, как switchover  произошел, и были добавленны ещё 2($2) поля то последние $2 поля появились на DB3, а вот  поля $1 отсутсвуют.

---

**Вопрос**
 можно ли как-то отресторить эти 3 поля ($1) на DB3 чтобы не возникало потери данных? 
(потому что если на тестовых базах то эти 3 поля это не много, а вот в продакшен базах их будет намного больше)

Comment: Решение проблемы нашел:

Нужно записать время остановки пампа **важно!!!**
-------------------
после переключения делаем если памп один то : 
      Меняем в пампе RMTHOST
и выполняем следющие команды:
    ggsci  src> alter extract {pump_name} begin {дата и время выключения пампа}

    ggsci  src> start {pump_name}



    ggsci trg> alter replicat {replicat_name} begin {дата и время выключения пампа}

Comment: @Viktorov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer , здесь написано что только после 15 баллов репутации, или я что-то не правильно понял

Comment: @Viktorov то ж чужие) если не сложно можете оформить ответом, пожалуйста)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаг 1. Записываем время остановки пампа.

Шаг 2. Вносим изменения в поле RMTHOST

Шаг 3. Изменяем и перезапускаем памп на источнике:

```
alter extract {pump_name} begin {дата и время выключения пампа} 
start {pump_name}
```

Шаг 4. Изменяем репликат на приемнике:

```
alter replicat {replicat_name} begin {дата и время выключения пампа}
```